# children component receiving "undefined" from an array of object prop

Tags: reactjs, arrays, components, undefined, react-props

I have a parent component that has an array of objects state, this state is passing to a children component. When I receive this prop and console.log, returns undefined.

PARENT

```
import { useState } from "react";

import Children from './Children'

import cardsData from "../cardsData";

const Parent = () => {
 
  const [cards, setCards] = useState(cardsData); // set cardsData in a state

  return (
    <div className='flex flex-col w-full  my-4 gap-4 rounded-full md:grid grid-cols-4 md:grid-row-3'>
        <Children
          cards={cards}
        />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Parent
```

CHILDREN

```
const Children = ({ cards }) => {
  console.log({cards});

  return (
    <div className="bg-white w-full h-60 md:col-span-2 rounded-lg">
      {cards[0].title}
    </div>
  );
};

export default CardSpanCol2;
```

MY DATA

```
const cardsData = [
        {
            id:1,
            type: "about",
            title: "Gabriel Barros",
            subTitle: "Web Development",
            text: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the",
        },{
            id:2,
            type: "about",
            picture: "./assets/me.jpg"
        },{
            id:3,
            type: "media",
            title:"Twitter"
        }
    ]


export default cardsData;
```

CONSOLE.LOG:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7owy.png)

ERROR: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

Comment: are you sure you're not calling `setCards` anywhere else?

Comment: Is `Children` component or `CardSpanCol2` (btw this component is missing in what you've posted) used anywhere else in your entire application? Since in logs it actually logs as both defined and undefined, you are possibly looking at 2 or more different instantiations of the same component. one of which might not have the cards prop passed. You may have done this unknowingly by importing from the wrong file. Use your IDE to check what references the file with `Children` component in it.

Comment: @AlexeyBykovskii i'm sure!

Comment: @adsy in my project is CardSpanCol2, but to post here I changed it for Children to be easier to understand. I just forgot to change the export name. About the logs, I am pretty sure that I just have log the data in the component Children

Comment: My question was not about where you log (which yes, is in children), it's about where `Children `/`CardSpanCol2` is *used* in the project and if it is used in multiple places.

Comment: I agree, based on this code, everything should be fine, but if this array is used somewhere else, then this could be the reason

Answer (score 0):

Error in the Children component, you need to change the base string to "export default Children;"

Answer (score 0):

When you want to pass down an Array of Objects you could try the following:

```
const Children = ( cards ) => {
   // notice the missing curly brackets
   console.log(cards)
   //your other code
```

Unfortunately I am still looking for an explanation, but this works for me so far.